# Files.move() in Java giving a FilesSystemException error because folder is "being used by another process," but it's not

Tags: java, file-move

I want to move a single file to another folder, but I can't because *"it is being used by another process."* This is my code:

```
static File myFile = new File("C:\\filepath");
static File myFolder = new File("C:\\folderpath");

public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws IOException {
    fileMove();
}

public static void fileMove() 
        throws IOException {
    Files.move(myFile.toPath(), myFolder.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    return;
}
```

Error message:
**Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\folderpath: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.**

I've tried out different files, different folders, but everytime it says the file is being used. I've tested it with a basic text file that was definitely closed and not being used when I tested it, but I still get the error. Does anyone know what's going on? Or, is there another way to move files that won't have this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.nio.file.FileSystemException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924479/java-nio-file-filesystemexception-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it)

Comment: `Files.move(myFile.toPath(), myFolder.toPath().resolve (myFile.getName ()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);`

Comment: @alzee That solution did not give an error, but the file was not moved at all.

Comment: @rollback We have a winner! This fixes my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from user [rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4515989/rollback):

```
Files.move(myFile.toPath(), myFolder.toPath().resolve(myFile.getName()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: Didn't have the time to post a full answer, that's why I added it as an comment.
Explanation:
The second argument of `Files.move(Path, Path, CopyOption...)` has to be the destination path (including the destination filename). That's why you had to add `.resolve(myFile.getName())`

Answer (score -1):

I use:

```
public static void moveFile(String origen, String destino) throws IOException {
        Path FROM = Paths.get(origen);
        Path TO = Paths.get(destino);

        CopyOption[] options = new CopyOption[]{
            StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE

        };
        Files.move(FROM, TO, options);
    }
```