# Java 1.8: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: java, file

I'm working on a console App using Java 1.8 that will read JSON files from a directory. Each file will be processed and then moved to another folder. My problem is the error you see in the title of this question.

This is my function to list all the files in the folder

```
public static void search(final String pattern, final File folder, List<String> result) {
    for (final File f : folder.listFiles()) {

        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            search(pattern, f, result);
        }

        if (f.isFile()) {
            if (f.getName().matches(pattern)) {

                if(f.length() > 0) {
                    result.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
                }               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my function to read the file string

```
static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException
{
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
    return new String(encoded, encoding);
}
```

This is my function to move the file:

```
private static void moveFile(String filename){

    String pathFrom = moveFilesFrom + filename;
    String pathTo = moveFilesTo + filename;

    try {
        Files.move(Paths.get(pathFrom), Paths.get(pathTo));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Failed to move file from " + pathFrom + " to " + pathTo);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And finally how I consume these files. `result` is a `List<String>` returned from `search`:

```
for (String jsonFile : result) {

    try {

        String jsonString = readFile(jsonFile, Charset.defaultCharset());

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonString);
        JSONArray data = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("data");
        long linesAdded = processLines(data);
        totalItemsInserted = totalItemsInserted + linesAdded;

        File f = new File(jsonFile);
        //System.out.println("File "+ f.getName() +" added " + linesAdded + " items. Curent Total:" + totalItemsInserted);
        log.info("File "+ f.getName() +" has "+ data.size() +"items and added " + linesAdded + " items. Curent Total:" + totalItemsInserted);

        if(moveFiles){
            moveFile(f.getName());
        }

    } catch (IOException | ParseException | java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

How can I change my code to avoid this error, and if there is a way for me to unlock the files.

Comment: As the error suggests,
Some other process has locked the files.
I'd suggest use the TaskManager to find if there is an earlier instance of your program that's still running or maybe some other process that locked the file

Comment: @Vishal I'm checking that. I though that maybe when I read the files in the directory or read the string it wasn't "releasing the lock" after I did so.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46596095/5031209
Also can you see the logs and point out which line causes the error.